# Point a domain to a subdomain in CPanel

Tags: dns, subdomain, hosting, cpanel, a-records

I have looked around a bit and found similar questions but I can't seem to find one addressing this exactly.

I have a domain hosted with GoDaddy www.example.com.
I have hosting set up with hostgator on a subdomain: abc.differentsite.com

I want to point www.example.com's nameservers to my hosted subfolder at abc.differentsite.com.

Pointing just to the name servers would in theory go to the main website and not the subdomain folder. I could use forwarding with masking, but I would prefer to not go that route.

I know design firms do this as they have one hosting account and host multiple sites then just direct name servers to the correct place but I don't know how to tell it to find the subfolder and not the main one.

Thanks in advance, sorry if this is posted elsewhere I looked but didn't see this exact situation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's called 'addon domain' in CPanel; you can specify any document root folder when creating it, including the folder of your existing subdomain.

Alternatively, there are 'parked domains' you can redirect to any URL (even if you don't own the latter).

Comment: That is how I created the subdomain to begin with, but how would I use that to take a domain already existing on GoDaddy and point that to my now created "add-on domain" hosted on HostGator (entirely separate from GoDaddy)

Comment: Wait maybe I understand, so if I make a new add-on domain and use my domain name from GoDaddy (www.example.com) even though that is not hosted at HostGator itself, point the root folder to my subfolder on HostGator, then I go and point my DNS name servers from the www.example.com on GoDaddy to the main name servers for my HostGator and it will know to receive that and forward to the root folder because I specified the add-on domain as www.example.com?

Comment: Thanks, that worked. I was trying to overcomplicate it thinking that just adding the domain when it isn't controlled/hosted at that same registrar wouldn't allow it to redirect to the correct subfolder but it worked.

Comment: Yep, it doesn't matter who's the registar as long as the domain points at Hostgator's nameservers. Glad it helped. :)